# Language/framework to write Excel spreadsheets, webbased

Tags: excel, sqlite

I need to make a webpage (from scratch) that will interrogate a SQLite database (with a predetermined query) to produce an Excel compatible spreadsheet. I need to find a **lightweight** solution to implement this, but don't know where to look and what is recommended.

The page itself will be fairly vanilla, only takes two dates as input, and the query will be pretty much a single table dump between those two dates. I'm interested in how to port the data to a spreadsheet.

EDIT: Framework should have some sort of stock SQLite package.

P.S.: Can be for use with Excel 2007 (XLSX) or older. Which ever way it goes, the page will be set to one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe PHP and [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) will suite your needs.